# Microsoft Access ? wildcard showing blank return

Tags: ms-access, wildcard

SELECT prod_id, prod_name
FROM Products
WHERE prod_name LIKE '?? inch teddy bear';

This is the code, it should return:

12 inch teddy bear
18 inch teddy bear

Instead I get nothing. New to SQL, go easy on me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the substring `?? inch teddy bear` inside of a larger string, then you may add `*` wildcard markers to your `LIKE` expression:

```
SELECT prod_id, prod_name
FROM Products
WHERE prod_name LIKE '*## inch teddy bear*';
```